# Why is my python console running slow even for simple commands?

Tags: python, performance, pycharm, anaconda

I have a script that takes about 90 seconds to run and it creates a dataframe that has 200,000 rows and 50 columns. (I've created larger datasets on this computer before without issue) When I run the initial script it runs at ideal speed. Then if I want to explore the data in the console after everything comes to a drag, even something simple like df.columns.

I stuck df.columns in the original script and it printed within a split second of it's turn in the script. But still when I then type it into the console afterwards I get the message "Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on." Then it loads for 30 full seconds before spitting out the columns.

What is causing this slowdown?

Specs: python 3.8, conda env, Pycharm 2020.2

Comment: Check your amount of available RAM as it may be due to memory swapping. Did you try with another terminal and a standard Python implementation (ie. not Conda and a minimal number of modules)?

Comment: @JérômeRichard upon further investigation it appears you are spot on. Pycharm is hanging during memory swap. any ideas how to alleviate?

Comment: I do not use PyCharm, so I do not know. Closing other apps like browsers can help. If the probem is only due to PyCharm, it is probably better to report a bug on they [bug-tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).